# Weights between the Last 2 layers keep getting negative

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, python, backpropagation, numpy

TL;DR weights between the last 2 layers keep getting negative to the point that the softmax(z) of the output layer can't divide by zero ( e^-750 ~= 0 thus deciding by 0)

I am making a Neural Network from scratch and just when I thought I finished a problem appears and I can't seem to fix it. *RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide* appears and it seems to be caused by the softmax function in the output layer when I am calculating the derivative of the softmax as softmax(z)(1 - softmax (z)) as a part of the error of the output layer with the given formula:

[image]

So then I started investigating the problem and it seems that the vector z(L) gets bigger and bigger in the negative direction after every iteration (mean value of the vector is around -744.5) so by the 19000 - 20000 iteration in the MNIST training of the 1st epoch, it spits out the above-mentioned error. So I investigated a bit more and by printing the average value of the weight matrix between the last 2 layers, I see that it is steadily increasing in the negative direction after every iteration (average weights of -14.9).

The binary classifier that I ran before this test works like a charm and reducing the Learning Rate over a fewer number of epochs could converge; it still just postpones the problem. And now I am stuck, and I don't know why are my weights behaving like that. Any help would be much appreciated!

Here are the formulas that I use for backpropagation along with the Python code:

***OUTPUT LAYER ERROR***
[image]

```
self.layers[-1].error = np.multiply(self.dcost(y, self.layers[-1].a),
                        self.layers[-1].dactivation(self.layers[-1].z))
```

***HIDDEN LAYER ERROR***
[image]

Weights between layer **L** and **L+1** are associated with the layer **L+1**

```
for layer in reversed(self.layers[1:-1]):   
    layer.error = (np.dot(np.transpose(self.layers[self.layers.index(layer)+1].weights),
                  self.layers[self.layers.index(layer)+1].error)) * layer.dactivation(layer.z)
```

***CALCULATING GRADIENT***
[image]

```
for layer in self.layers[1:]:
    layer.gradients = np.dot(layer.error.reshape(-1, 1),
                      self.layers[self.layers.index(layer)-1].a.reshape(1, -1))
```

***UPDATING THE WEIGHTS***

```
layer.weights -= self.lr * layer.gradients
```

Comment: I think this is why the LogSumExp trick exists https://blog.feedly.com/tricks-of-the-trade-logsumexp/

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Damn, I hate being one of those guys who post a question this big for a problem that should be trivial.

Comment: It's only trivial once you know the answer. I wouldn't be worried about it

Comment: Can you post the link as the answer because I want to check it as the answer, you really helped me!